# identical target="_blank" behaving differently for different hrefs

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

In IE, LinkedIn opens in a new tab, SO opens in a new window.  Why is that when both are identically structured (`target="_blank"`)?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="xlink">
    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=123" target="_blank" class="xlinkedin"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/123/abc" target="_blank" class="xstackoverflow"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.xlink 
{
    float:right;
    margin-top:18px;
}

.xlink li 
{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.xstackoverflow 
{
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:#222 url('../images/stackoverflow.png') no-repeat 4px 3px;
}

.xlinkedin 
{
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:#222 url('../images/linkedin.png') no-repeat 4px 3px;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE? Tested in IE 10 and both links open in a new tab: http://jsfiddle.net/6K57W/1/show/

Comment: Both links open in a new tab here.. do you have any JS that may be interfering?

Comment: I tried it in IE 9, and both opens in a new tab.

Comment: @XaviLópez: ...or a new tab, depending on the settings in the browser.

Comment: @xec That's strange, testing in IE 10 both open in a new window

Comment: @anirudhvarma it depends on the browser settings - but both links should always behave the same, unless there is something else going on (js?).

Comment: there is no JS that would discriminate

Comment: Yep! that' right,I figured it out, both are opening in a different window, but atleast they are behaving the same

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in your browsers, some offer the option to open new windows in tabs.

Comment: but why would it behave differently for different links?